# Android Studio Debug and DDMS

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, ddms

Is there way to debug and ddms enabled at the same time? For example: add breakpoint to sms receiver, send sms with ddms and stop at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the the DDMS to send an SMS and debug it as the only way to do it is to disable the ADB integration within android studio and it needs this to debug.

Instead use the terminal window within Android Studio to telnet into the emulator console with:

```
telnet localhost <port number>
```

and send an SMS using the command:

```
sms send <senderPhoneNumber> <textmessage>
```

more details can be found at http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

You have button just right of RUN application.to make app on debug in running.

and you should check by tip and tricks og android studio for more.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, why not? I assume you're using Eclipse. Set a breakpoint in the Debug perspective, switch to the DDMS perspective, and send an SMS. You should stop at the breakpoint. You could also use the external DDMS application if you don't like switching perspectives.

Comment: Android Studio is in both the question title and tags, so I assume he's *not* running Eclipse.